# Error deploying ASP.NET WebApplication on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

recently I've been struggling to deploy my **ASP.NET Web Application on IIS** (I'm using Windows 10). I did everything exactly the same as it was written [here](http://www.loganfranken.com/blog/284/developing-a-web-application-locally-with-iis7-and-web-developer-express/). Things went smoothly and nicely till I tried to open my application (*.aspx*) on IIS in browser. And I got the [ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrieI.png). I tried to search for the solution in google/stockoverflow, but seems nothing goes right for me or I'm really bad at searching.

Maybe any suggestions to tackle the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens if you add an `html` file (not `aspx`) and browser to it?

Comment: The same error. It seems that something is wrong not on the IIS, is it possible?

Comment: you should open http://example.local/ instead of localhost as mentioned in the article

Comment: on windows 10 you might need to run VS with administrator rights

Comment: @IvanSalo did not help :(

Comment: Have you tried to get the full error info?

Comment: Yes, it seems IIS isn't installed or running - the `html` file test points to it (instead of other errors like application/ASP.Net installation, etc.). Not going to be pretty, [but this is how IIS is usually enabled/installed in Wnidows 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/112455/how-to-install-iis-8-on-windows-8/). Hth.

Comment: IIS is installed correctly. Everythings looks nice. But my on localhost whether IIS is turned on or off, the same error applies. I even tried to launch empy ASP.NET Application "Hello World" and also tried to put index.html file - and nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Without actually seeing your setup in iis itself, it is hard to determine what the problem is.  But the first thing I would check is to see if your localhost site in iis is bound correctly Please see [here](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/bindings/binding) on correctly setting up your bindings.

Comment: Seems its okay. I'm out of ideas what to do :D What would you like to see in the setup itself?

Answer (score 0):

This won't be the final answer, but to begin with, always get the full error info first.

Please open Event Viewer in Windows, and under Windows Logs hopefully there will hopefully be some error pertaining to ASP.NET.  Can you get the info from that and post it?

Doing this may also help
https://www.webwiz.net/kb/asp-tutorials/friendly-HTTP-error-messages.htm

UPDATE BASED ON COMMENTS:

I think you need to uninstall and reinstall IIS, it sounds like something is wrong there.  You can do it from add/remove Windows components, eg.

http://www.howtogeek.com/112455/how-to-install-iis-8-on-windows-8/

You may need to re-register ASP.NET afterwards

To fix IIS mappings for ASP.NET, run the Aspnet_regiis.exe utility:
Click Start, and then click
Run.
In the Open text box, type cmd, and then press ENTER.
At the command prompt, type the following, and then press ENTER:
"%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\version\aspnet_regiis.exe" -i
In this path, version represents the version number of the .NET Framework that you installed on your server. You must replace this placeholder with the actual version number when you type the command.

Comment: @dusmanass where did you get that?  Was there any more detail?

Comment: Internet Explorer says:

Most likely causes:
•The website is under maintenance.
•The website has a programming error.
 
This error (HTTP 500 Internal Server Error) means that the website you are visiting had a server problem which prevented the webpage from displaying.

Comment: @dusmanass thanks, is the URL in the error actually " localhost/MyApp/Default.aspxhttp:/localhost/MyApp/Default.aspx", i.e. repeated twice like it appears in your comment?  I assume you're not entering the URL twice like that?

Comment: Sorry, it was just a mistake :D Just found error one more: 

The machine-default permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
 and APPID 
 to the user **** from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Farlex.581429F59E1D8_2.1.0.18_x64__wyegy4e46y996 SID (S-1-15-2-1267739591-1137297291-83386112-1979864472-959024908-3354412519-3889419757). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

Comment: @dusmanass sorry am unclear, was the comment the mistake, or was the URL you were using the mistake?  Is it working?

Comment: The URL was not correct so I presume, this is where that error in event viewer stems from. My mistake. But the second error I posted above might result from the problem I confront, at least seems so, does not it?

Comment: @dusmanass well, that error could be a red herring, perhaps try https://www.velocityreviews.com/threads/fixed-the-machine-default-permission-settings-do-not-grant-local-activation-permission-for-the-com.509809/ there are tons of results for the first line of your error on google.  You can also ZIP your solution and put it on dropbox or something and I'll try it if you like.

Comment: Have tried this as well - didn't help. I don't really think that the problem lies within IIS or my ASP.NET application. To me, something is wrong with my localhost settings / properties because whatever I would do - the very same error occurs. Anyway, really appreciate your effort to find a way out :) @Jim W

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up IIS correctly? same with asp.net(Need to [register](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx) too).

Additional:

> 1. Check IIS if Directory Browsing is enabled.
> 2. Check application pool framework (It must be the with project framework.)

Comment: IIS is set up correctly. Enabled Directory Browsing through command prompt. Pool framework matches the ASP.NET Web Application framework. Seems everything is fine. I dare say that something is wrong not within IIS. I cannot even open my localhost outside the ISS: the same error lies there (HTTP ERROR 500). Something is  wrong with my localhost, is it possible?

Comment: check your web config file.

Comment: May I ask you what I should check there? @reds